# What is the significance of an organic compound's M peak?

Tags: terminology, mass-spectrometry

**Background**

On the topic of identifying an organic compounds using peaks generated in *Mass Spectrometry*, a rule of thumb expressed in the UK educational textbook, CGP, is that that "the M peak is the one with the second highest mass/charge ratio".

**Question**

What is the significance of this M peak anyway?

Comment: The largest peak is representative of the most stable isotope produced, referred to as the bass peak.

Comment: Cheers @LukeAutrey!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"M" stands for **molecular** ion.  It is often represented as $\ce{M, M^{+} or M^{+~.}}$. In the mass spec experiment, an electron is knocked out of some of the sample molecules.  The peak at M/q (q=1) represents the molecular weight of the entire molecule, less an electron, before it fragments to smaller ions.  From precise measurement of the molecular ion (*e.g*. 82.34567890) you can determine the exact molecular formula of your sample compound.  This can help greatly with sample identification.